# WireShark: my Plugin cannot be loaded by WireShark 1.8.4

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have written my own plugin (dissector) for the WireShark Framework. Now it is working witht the WireShark I build together with the plugin. But when I put these dll-Files into the Plugin directory of installed WireShark, it cannot be loaded. I get the message:

```
Runtime Error!
Programm: C:\Programme\System\WireShark-1.8.4\wireshark.exe
R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

After this, I get this message, perhaps a little bit more details.

```
Couldn't load module c:\Programme\System\Wireshark-1.8.4\plugins\1.8.4\wagocia.dll: `c:\Programme\System\Wireshark-1.8.4\plugins\1.8.4\wagocia.dll': Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.
```

I have compiled the WireShark and my Plugin with the MSVC2008EE. 
Do I get the error due to the difference of Compiler Version of Plugins and WireShark from Web? Because with the WireShark I build (also with MSVC2008EE) everything works fine.

Best Regards
Björn

Comment: You *must* compile your plugin with VC2010 if you want it to be compatible with  WireShark-1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile your plugin with VC2010 for compatibility with VC2010.